# Apache can't bind to address [::]:80, already in use

Tags: linux, port, lamp, apache-http-server

I run `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start` and get this:

```
Starting httpd2 (prefork) (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
startproc:  exit status of parent of /usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork: 1
                                                                                                                   failed
```

This means something is using port 80 right? So I run `sudo netstat -anp | grep 80` :

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.252:48407     72.233.69.5:80          ESTABLISHED 22710/chrome        
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.252:59151     74.125.226.68:80        ESTABLISHED 22710/chrome        
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.252:39954     209.85.225.102:80       ESTABLISHED 22710/chrome        
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.252:59845     74.125.226.69:80        ESTABLISHED 22710/chrome        
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.252:48405     72.233.69.5:80          ESTABLISHED 22710/chrome        
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.252:45756     208.44.23.97:80         ESTABLISHED 22710/chrome        
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.252:57631     50.16.231.47:80         ESTABLISHED 22710/chrome        
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.252:48404     72.233.69.5:80          ESTABLISHED 22710/chrome        
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     221080192 22759/ --disable-we 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     221080191 22886/npwrapper.lib 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     221080189 22907/npviewer.bin  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     221080188 2351/Xorg           @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     221080128 22886/npwrapper.lib 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     221080094 2351/Xorg           @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     221069080 22710/chrome        
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     220845880 5186/master         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     156358076 24712/gvfs-gphoto2- 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     156358066 3025/dbus-daemon    @/tmp/dbus-eEbaAghTui
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     156358065 24709/gvfs-afc-volu 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     156358058 24704/gvfs-gdu-volu 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     156026080 24604/sde (every 2  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     81194780 1975/dbus-daemon    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     226086 9080/kwalletmanager 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     226617 9080/kwalletmanager 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     225968 9080/kwalletmanager 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     226597 9080/kwalletmanager 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     23808  1975/dbus-daemon    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     23807  4358/nepomukservice 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16680  3025/dbus-daemon    @/tmp/dbus-eEbaAghTui
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     15080  4052/kgpg           
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12380  1975/dbus-daemon    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9803   2351/Xorg           @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9802   3024/dbus-launch    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8062   2728/polkitd        
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8051   2658/console-kit-da 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8014   1975/dbus-daemon    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8004   1975/dbus-daemon    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
```

It only seems that Chrome is using 80 so I don't see what the problem is. Any ideas?

Comment: Chrome uses port 80 on the **remote** server. So that's not your problem.

Comment: My first thought when I see this kind of question is always "Do you have Skype installed?" :)

Comment: No :) does skype wrongfully takeover 80?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome is not listening on a local port `80` but just connected to a remote port `80`.

I don't really see a problem. But try to specify an IP to listen on, as it seems to be failing on IPv6  right now...

Comment: How would I do that? Doesn't apache automatically look for 80?

Comment: @MaxMackie: Read the documention, you have to specify in the `httpd.conf` in the `conf` folder something along the lines of `Listen 12.34.56.78:80` if just `80` fails. You could specify it to listen on multiple IPs by providing multiple lines...